Sharing Data Between Swift Views?
I am trying to get my head around sharing data with multiple views using @Obervable protocol but having trouble making it work.
I have created a simple app to demonstrate the issue I am having, which you will see.   It comprises of the:

DemoApp.swift
ContentView.swift
Model.swift
SecondView.swift

The trouble I am having is passing the data through to the ‘SecondView’
All works fine within the ContentView, but outside that, no good.
Can someone have a look at this simple code and tell me where I have got it all wrong.
Pete
DemoApp.swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct DemoApp: App {
    @State private var data = ModelData()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(data)
        }
    }
}

ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Bindable var data = ModelData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                TextField("Value", text: $data.value)
                Text("\(data.value)")
                
                NavigationLink {
                    SecondView()
                        .onAppear() {
                            data.Compute()
                        }
                } label: {
                    Text("Button")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Model.swift
import Foundation
import Observation

@Observable
class ModelData {
    var value = ""
    
    func Compute() {
        print(self.value)
    }
}

SecondView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct SecondView: View {
    var data = ModelData()

    var body: some View {
        Text("You Typed: \(data.value)")
    }
}

#Preview {
    SecondView()
}

RESULTS AFTER CHANGE
I made the suggested changes and they resolved the issue, but now, as soon as I entered: @Environment (ModelData.self) var data in the 'ContentView', I am now unable to preview the View.
I end up receiving this fatal error:

Any ideas ?

Have a look at this link Managing model data in your app, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app. The idea is to pass the one and only ModelData to other views, not create a new one in every view.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

you can't init a class (i.e. heap object) with @State like that its a memory leak, needs to be a value like struct.

It is perfectly valid to declare @State private var data = ModelData().
Apple gives examples of that, and also gives the reasons, see the link.
Apple specifically says, this "Create the source of truth for model data".
See the official docs here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app#Create-the-source-of-truth-for-model-data

Currently you have multiple ModelData() that have no relations to each other. You need to pass a single source of truth, the ModelData() in your DemoApp to the other views.
So try this approach:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(ModelData.self) var data // <--- here

    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var data = data  // <--- here
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                TextField("Value", text: $data.value)
                Text("\(data.value)")
                
                NavigationLink {
                    SecondView()
                        .onAppear() {
                            data.Compute()
                        }
                } label: {
                    Text("Button")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Observable
class ModelData {
    var value = ""
    
    func Compute() {
        print(self.value)
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @Environment(ModelData.self) var data // <--- here

    var body: some View {
        Text("You Typed: \(data.value)")
    }
}

See this link Managing model data in your app
EDIT-1:
Alternatively if you want to edit the data, you could use this setup for SecondView
struct SecondView: View {
    @Bindable var data: ModelData

    var body: some View {
        Text("You Typed: \(data.value)")
        TextField("", text: $data.value).border(.red)
    }
}

And in ContentView call SecondView(data: data)

Absolutely nailed it.   Thank you so much, this has resolved the issue.  Now it's time to sit down and digest what I have just done then understand why.
If I was now to place a TextField on the 'SecondView' then I would also need to place: "@Bindable var data = data"   in the code to connect it to the Environment ?

Yes, as simple as that, like in the ContentView, in the body: @Bindable var data = data
and TextField("", text: $data.value)

Updated my answer with another way of passing the ModelData to your SecondView
